# Update timestamps in a Json file with Python script

Tags: python, json, timestamp

I would like your help with updating a Json file *times.json* with a Python script that will update each of the following time stamps:

For Id1: CurrentTS-9days, Id2: CurrentTS-7days, Id3: CurrentTS-5days.. etc

I tried to use `datetime.date.today()` but I just couldn't get to a full script that works.

```
 [{
    "creationTime": 1543647600000,
    "id":1
    },
{
    "creationTime": 1543647600000,
    "id":2
    },
{
    "creationTime": 1543647600000,
    "id":3
    }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, I assume the field "creationTime" is the date converted to seconds, so I based my implementation on that. Here is a quick code to update the time stamps given the requirement:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

data = [{"creationTime": 1543647600000,"id":1},
{"creationTime": 1543647600000,"id":2},
{"creationTime": 1543647600000,"id":3}]

day_start = 9
for tuple in data:
    print('Previous: ' , tuple['creationTime'])
    tuple['creationTime'] -=  int(timedelta(days = day_start).total_seconds())
    day_start -= 2
    print('After: ', tuple['creationTime'])
```

This is what I understood from the question, if something is not the way you intended it to be, please comment and I will try to look.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
I need the output to be the same Json file with only the requested changes and it should look like:

[{"creationTime": currentTime-9days,"id":1},
{"creationTime":  currentTime-7days,"id":2},
{"creationTime":  currentTime-2days,"id":3}]